# Has someone implemented code(in javascript) to get last seven days consolidated reputation thorough API?

Tags: discussion, api-v2, reputation

I am trying to get user's reputation for last seven days. I want to get total reputation user has earned on specific day. Has someone implemented a way to do this in javascript?

I know I can do this by fetching reputation change history for last seven days and then calculate it by iterating through data, but if someone has already implemented it then I can reuse it.